# Is there a way to create a type 3 grammar for this language?

Tags: formal-languages

I'm trying to find a grammar of the highest type possible for this language:

L={0^2n 1^(n-1)|n>=1}
I only managed to do this:

```
S->00X
X->00X1|λ
```

Which is not type 3. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to type 3 (if that's even possible).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: You can use the pumping lemma to show that `L` is not regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it, because `L` is not a regular language.

Assume that `L` is regular. Let `w = 0^(2p)1^(p-1)` for some integer `p>=1`, so that `|w| > p`.  Further, consider the strings `x`, `y`, and `z` such that `w = xyz` with `|xy| <= p`, which means both `x` and `y` are sequences of 0s (since `p < 2p`). By the pumping lemma, any string of the form `xy^nz` is *also* in `L`, but that means we can increase the number of 0s without increasing the number of 1s found in `z`. Thus, our assumption that `L` is regular must be false.